"Has been processed" or "is processed" in an email
I've drafted an email that users of an application would receive when we activate their services. A sentence in the email reads:

Once your payment has been processed, we will activate your services as soon as possible.

I'm not a native English speaker, but this sentence 'felt' good to use in this case. A colleague (also a non native speaker) said that the sentence should read "Once your payment is processed, we will activate your services as soon as possible". She told that using has been could imply that the action of processing the payment has started in the past and is still continuing in the present (so according to her, it implies that we will activate the services during processing of the payment, instead of after the payment is processed).
What is the correct version to use in this case? Should I use "has been processed" or "is processed". Does it actually matter which version is used, or are both correct?

Both sentences are understandable, grammatical  and even interchangeable "Once we have received payment…” = as soon as the money arrives  "Once we receive payment…" it's the same thing, perhaps your coworker's version is a tad more formal but both are "correct"

Thank you for your response! So both versions ("Once your payment has been processed, we will activate your services as soon as possible." and "Once your payment is processed, we will activate your services as soon as possible.") are "correct"? Is one of the versions more "suitable" or more "normal" to use in an automated email?

Best ask your manager or supervisor..

Sorry but I'm the manager. It's just that we're unsure which version is best to use in English as we are unsure if using has been or is in this sentence has a different meaning. Both versions "feel" okay as non native speakers, but is there a difference in the way it's interpreted as native speakers (regarding "progress" or "time")? (Sorry if my question is not very clear as I'm having trouble explaining it precisely in English)

I cannot tell you which one to choose, in my opinion both versions are fine.

Okay, thank you very much!

Both are equally good:

Once your payment has been processed ...


Once your payment is processed ...

and both has been processed and is processed mean completion.
This is incorrect:

using has been could imply that the action of processing the payment has started in the past and is still continuing in the present ...

On the other hand,  if it is once your payment processing has started, it would have that meaning.
